# Getting over the "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." without any option to enable error reporting

Tags: php

I have a really stupid problem and I have no idea how to solve it. One of my clients wanted me to put a simple PHP script on his website, which is hosted on a Windows/PHP shared hosting.

The problem is, that they have error reporting disabled and I don't have access to error logs. The only thing that I'm getting is

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I've tried

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

foreach(1 as $i);
?>
```

but it doesn't change anything, I'm still getting generic 500 error. Is there any other way to make PHP display error messages? The hosting tech support is completely non-responsive, but I'd like to solve this somehow, even with some hackery, which means I don't care how dirty the solution is, all I care about is that I can see the error message in detail.

I tried to add custom error handler as you guys suggested, but I'm still getting the 500 page and no error log written

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Prague"); // tried commenting this line out, didn't help

function fileLogHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $logFile = "error.log";
    $f = fopen($logFile, "a") or die("Couldn't open log file for write");
    fwrite($f, strftime("%c") . " $errstr on line $errline\nin file $errfile\n\n");
}

set_error_handler("fileLogHandler");

foreach(1 as $i);
?>
```

When I execute this on my local machine, it works as expected

```
$ php -f test.php  && cat error.log 
Fri Oct 28 15:40:14 2011 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 12
in file /Users/darth/Sites/shalamar/test.php
```

but it doesn't work on the host machine ...

I tried to dumb down the whole script to

```
<?php
$logFile = "error.log";
$f = fopen($logFile, "a");
fwrite($f, "Hi");
?>
```

and ended up realizing, that I probably don't have write permissions to the folder. The problem is, it's a windows server, and if I try to change permissions via FileZilla, I get the lovely

```
Command:    SITE CHMOD 666 error.log
Response:   500 'SITE CHMOD 666 error.log': command not understood
```

**I tried to google around and it looks like I can't set file permissions via FTP.**

Sending the log over email also ends up in 500 error

```
mail("mysecret@email.com", "Voice of desperation");
```

Any suggestions now?

**Update:** Thanks for all the suggestions so far, but I found out I don't even have access to the filesystem, so I can't write to a log file. At least that's what it looks like, so I talked to the tech support guys, and they say they'll look into it within the next week.

Comment: It might be because the whole script is parsed before being executed. Try moving the error_reporting and ini_set calls to the bottom of the script.

Comment: Have you tried to define a custom error handler? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @kasimir oh yes I have, but I don't have access to the filesystem and I can't send out emails ... already emailed tech support to give me write access, because otherwise I don't see any solution possible

Answer (score 2):

that's what **error logs** are for.

try to create `.user.ini` or `php.ini` files in the same directory contains

```
error_log = phperrors.log
```

(absolute path is preferred)

then run your script again and then look for this file and it's contents.

Comment: It sounded like his hosting people suck, and he probably doesn't have access to that.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I don't have access to php.ini

Comment: @Darth read my lips: **create** a file **in the same directory**

Comment: @Tim  doesn't have access to what? to the same directory where the problem script is?

Answer (score -1):

How about using [set_error_handler()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) then writing the error message into a file?

Answer (score -1):

To get the PHP Errors by email:

```
function custom_error_handler ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
    $content  = "Time ".date("d.m.Y G:i")."\n\n";
    $content .= "Error No: ".$errno."\n";
    $content .= "Error String: ".$errstr."\n";
    $content .= "Error File: ".$errfile."\n";
    $content .= "Error Line: ".$errline."\n\n";
    mail("youremail@yourdomain.com", "[ERROR HANDLER]", $content);
}

set_error_handler ("custom_error_handler");
```